# Loops cuts and geometry

Tags: modeling, edges, subdivision-surface

Beginner here.

Can't work out what's wrong with the mesh to get the below. Have made sure there aren't any doubles and that everything is a quad and the normals are pointing in the right direction,

[image]

Also when trying to select a loop it seems to select the faces?

[image]

Any help greatly appreciated

Thanks

Comment: My guess is it might be the normals. Try selecting all geometry with A, then press Alt+N and choose "Recalculate outside"

Comment: Try A to select everything and then M to merge by distance and increasing the distance. It looks like you right clicked after either an extrude or inset and have doubles.

Comment: It could also be creased edges, Try A to select everything, then Shift + E and type -1 to clear the creases.

Comment: can you share your blend file https://blend-exchange.com